# Mammavian Integument

Tags: creature-design, evolution, hair

Mammavians are a common type of animal across many worlds, which have traits of both mammals and birds

One trait they often have is a unique integument, which produces both mammalian hair, avian feathers, and often some sort of intermediary fiber alongside

However, hair and feathers seem pretty similar, so it seems like most of these species would adapt to only have a single type of integument

Is there any way to justify this multiple integument?

Comment: What do you mean by justify? What difficulties are you having justifying this feature? Why do you need to justify it? Without knowing this information we can't meaningfully answer this question.

Comment: Hair and feathers are *part of* the integument, they are not *produced by* the integument. You probably meant to say "a unique integument, comprising both hair and feathers". (The word *integumentum* means a covering, and by extension something which conceals or protects.)

Comment: P.S. The stereotypical [pennaceous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pennaceous_feather) feathers are not the only [kind of feathers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feather#Classification). Birds also have [down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_feather) feathers and hair-like [filoplumes](https://www.britannica.com/science/filoplume).

Comment: Hint: if you would substitute the word "integument" by "skin" this question would be more clear for non-English speakers. I had to google the term.

Comment: @Goodies: The word integument does not mean what the original poster thinks it means. The hair of mammals and the feather of birds are part of their integument, they are not "produced by" the integument. It is a technical word, and it has similar forms in other European languages; for example, in French it's *tégument*. (It is borrowed from Latin,  derived from the verb *tego* "I cover", from which Latin also has the much better known *toga*.)

Comment: @AlexP clear, thx for the explanation... it also occurred to me that "skin" could work better when talking about producing hair, or producing feathers. In Dutch we'd say "hairs grow out of the skin", or "from the skin" if translated literally. The skin would "make" or "produce" hair, or feathers.

Comment: Birds alone have both scales and feathers, 2 completely different types of coverings, justified by different purposes. Birds also have different types of feathers, much like how mammals can have hairs with different purposes and reptiles have different types of scales (and if we really want to get down to it, teeth originally came from scales in primitive fish, so there's that). It's hard to understand why they couldn't have both without information on what would cause them to ultimately favor a single one over the other in your setting.

Comment: Remember that often in nature if a trait brings enough benefits to justify the cost of maintaining it, then more often than not there are little to no natural pressures motivating its loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our own world birds have hairs, its just that it is mostly in the inner ear. Birds also have genes to regenerate hair cells, which we mammals don't, which means that if a bird ever had hair on their head they would be way less likely to ever go bald.

Now hair and feathers may usually have overlapping roles, but there are things that only one or the other can do. You can't fly with hair and you can't have feeler feathers. A bird might have sensory hairs on their face akin to the whiskers of a dog or cat in order to get a better sense of their surroundings in tight places. Or these could grow throughout a line around the body to serve as a medium to host symbiotic microbes or bugs, like sloths do.

Comment: The hairs of the hair cells in the inner ear are in no way similar to the hair on the body of mammals. They are called hairs in everyday speech, but the actual name of the structure is [stereocilia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereocilia) (singular stereocilium).

Answer (score 1):

The hair is used as underlayer, to ensure thermal insulation. The feathers are used as outer layer to protect from rain and dust, together with providing additional thermal insulation.

Comment: that's what down feathers are for, and they do their job extremely well. that's why our most expensive jackets are full of down feathers, and not hair.

Comment: @daisydaisyg you might be missing the whole point of worldbuilding, where reality is just a starting point, not a barbed wire covered fence